# How to access an element of a multidimensional array by single variable representing [i, j]?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a 4x4 array. 
I want to give some nick name (variable) to a specific element, but I found no intuitive solution.

Question: How to access a specific element by single element?
I intent to use an alias for each element for future readability.
Let future maintainers know every element's meaning.

```
int[] arr = new int[ 4,4 ];

//This code won't compile
var YtoZ = "1,2";
int value = arr[ YtoZ ]; // equivalent to arr[1,2];
```

I checked [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) but its example is accessed by hardcoded value.

I tried following keywords:

- "C# access Multidimensional Array index by single variable"
- "c# specify multidimensional array by variable"

Most related post is using tuple to save it: 
[How to Save a Multidimensional Array Index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853038/how-to-save-a-multidimensional-array-index)

Other results are mostly how to declare it:

- [How can I declare a two dimensional string array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3814145/4123703)
- [C# declaring a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636344/c-sharp-declaring-a-2d-array)
- [Creating an array of two-dimensional arrays in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851509/creating-an-array-of-two-dimensional-arrays-in-c-sharp)

My workaround might be wrapping an array with overloaded enum value, but I feel like thinking too much.

```
    public class wrapper
    {
        public enum NickName
        {
            X2x = 0,
            X2y = 10,
            Z2x = 2020,
            X2z = 2000,
        }
        // Provide [] operator access
        public object this[ NickName index ]
        {
            get
            {
                int i = (int)index % 100;
                int j = (int)index / 100;
                return m_Matrix[ i, j ];
            }
        }

        float[,] m_Matrix = new float[ 4, 4 ];
    }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a reference to a specific element within your array of value types? It sounds as if you may wish to use a pointer.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood I just want to saving my method from returning multiple indexes or tuple. So I don't have to write `array[ tuple.item1, tuple.item2 ]`. Just `array[ variable ]`

Comment: You can easily save and pass a reference to the element itself (`ref int value = ref arr[1, 2];`). Depending on what you are [actually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) doing, this may or may not mean you don't need to pass around the address.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks! This should be better than my workaround. I was wondering if there is a more intuitive way to do it.

Comment: @GSerg I did not know you could inline generate references to value types like that, very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @LouisGo, as per GSerg, see "Ref Locals" at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns. Every day's a learning day.